# <form:input> tag in jsp is not converting to input tag of html for map property of model class

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have Map of CategoryAttribute object in Category model class .Due to Some reason categoryAttributes map is not able bind with `<form:input>` tag of Spring Mvc in jsp, however category object is available to jsp page. I need to catch input of Category Attributes properties name and value to controller and persist to database how would I do that. I have tried but `<form:input>` tag is not converting into input field  please have a look where i have done mistake thanks for helping.

Category Model class

```
 @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY")
    public class Category implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
        protected Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
        @Index(name = "CATEGORY_NAME_INDEX", columnNames = { "NAME" })
        protected String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", targetEntity = CategoryAttribute.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
        @MapKey(name = "name")
        @BatchSize(size = 50)
        protected Map<String, CategoryAttribute> categoryAttributes = new HashMap<String, CategoryAttribute>();
    }
```

CategoryAttribute class

```
  @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE")
    public class CategoryAttribute implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE_ID")
        protected Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
        @Index(name = "CATEGORYATTRIBUTE_NAME_INDEX", columnNames = { "NAME" })
        protected String name;

        @Column(name = "VALUE")
        protected String value;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
        @Index(name = "CATEGORYATTRIBUTE_INDEX", columnNames = { "CATEGORY_ID" })
        protected Category category;
    }
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(CategoryController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CatalogItemService catalogItemService;

    public CatalogItemService getCatalogItemService() {
        return catalogItemService;
    }

    public void setCatalogItemService(CatalogItemService catalogItemService) {
        this.catalogItemService = catalogItemService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirectToForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String retrieveForm(@ModelAttribute Category category) {

        return "category";
    }
    //this function is responsible for sending the category object
    @RequestMapping(value = "/gencategory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String genCategoryList(Model model, @RequestParam("id") String id) {
        Category category = catalogItemService.findCategoryById(Long
                .parseLong(id));
        List<Category> categories = catalogItemService.findAllCategories();
        List<CategoryMapper> childCategories = category
                .getAllChildCategoryMappers();
        List<CategoryMapper> parentCategories = category.getAllParentCategoryMappers();
        model.addAttribute("categoryList", categories);
        model.addAttribute("childCategoryList", childCategories);
        model.addAttribute("parentCategoryList", parentCategories);


        List<String> inventoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
        inventoryList.add("ALWAYS_AVAILABLE");
        inventoryList.add("UNAVAILABLE");
        inventoryList.add("CHECK QUANTITY");

        List<String> fulfillmentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        fulfillmentList.add("Digital");
        fulfillmentList.add("Gift card");
        fulfillmentList.add("Pickup");
        fulfillmentList.add("Physical Pickup or Ship");
        fulfillmentList.add("Physical Ship");
        model.addAttribute("category", category);
        model.addAttribute("inventorIs", inventoryList);
        model.addAttribute("fulfillmentIs", fulfillmentList);
        return "generalcategory";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            @ModelAttribute("hiddenFormValue") String hiddenFormValue,
            Model model) {
        Category defaultParentCategory = catalogItemService
                .findCategoryById(Long.parseLong(hiddenFormValue));
        category.setDefaultParentCategory(defaultParentCategory);
        List<Category> categories = catalogItemService.findAllCategories();
        model.addAttribute("categoryList", categories);
        category.setId(29965L);
        catalogItemService.saveCategory(category);

        return "generalcategory";
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void customDateBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "activeStartDate",
                new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "activeEndDate",
                new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));

    }
}
```

generalcategory.jsp

```
<form:form  action="saveCategory" method="post" id="categoryForm" modelAttribute="category">
                    <c:set var="myRequestModel" value="${category}" scope="request" />
                    <c:out value="${myRequestModel.categoryAttributes}"></c:out>

                    <jsp:include page="categoryattributemodal.jsp">
                        <jsp:param name="category" value="${myRequestModel}" />
                    </jsp:include>
            </form:form>
```

CategoryAttribute.jsp page where i am trying to map the map object of category class

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalCategoryAttribute" tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModelCattLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="key">Key*:</label>
                                <div class='input-group date' id='name'>
                                     <form:input path="category.categoryAttribute['name']" cssClass="form-control" /> 
                                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" /> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="key">Attribute Value*:</label>
                                <div class='input-group date' id='attributeValue'>
                                   <form:input path="category.categoryAttributes['value']" cssClass="form-control" /> 
                                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" /> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span class="text-muted"><input type="button" id="addCategoryAttrButton"
                    class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" /></span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the page where input field is not coming when try to bind map object of category class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to generate getters and Setters to all  member variables.

Second : In form:input should bind to member variable only. So please change

```
    <form:input path="category.categoryAttributes['value']" cssClass="form-ontrol" />
```

to

```
    <form:input path="category.categoryAttributes['Key of HashMap'].memberVariableInCategoryAttribute" cssClass="form-ontrol" />
```